# Image map with select option

Tags: javascript, html, image, select, mapping

How do I create a image map with separate `<select>`?

I need something like this:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Website map" usemap="#mapname" />
<map name="judete" id="judete">
    <area shape="poly" coords="474,300,485" href="#" alt="TL" judet="TL" text="Tulcea" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="309,393,305" href="#" alt="TR" judet="TR" text="Teleorman" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="498,336,501" href="#" alt="CT" judet="CT" text="Constanta" />
</map>
```

and I need to use the next code to click an area from map

```
<select name="judete">
  <option value="Tulcea">Tulcea</option>
  <option value="Teleorman">Teleorman</option>
  <option value="Constanta">Constanta</option>
</select>
```

Is it posible ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'll have to ask like this:

You mean you want a dropdown list next to the map in case the user can't click the places in the map?

Or do you mean a dropdown list to come out when you click a place on the map?

Either way, it is possible.